# Why does $\int_0^1 f_X(a-y) \ dy = \int_{a-1}^a f_X(y) \ dy $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^1 f_X(a-y) \ dy = \int_{a-1}^a f_X(y) \ dy $$

Is this some sort of substitution? Is it simply a matter of of subtracting $a$ and multiplying by $-1$ in both the function and the bounds? When I did that ended up with $$ \int_{a}^{a-1} f_X(y) \ dy$$

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a change of variables.

If $x=a-y$, then ${\rm d}x = -{\rm d}y$ and, while $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $x$ goes from $a$ to $a-1$. So
$$\int_{0}^{1} f(a-y)\,{\rm d}y = \int_{a}^{a-1} -f(x)\,{\rm d}x.$$

Comment: And $-f(x)=f(y)$?

Comment: No, ${\rm d}x=-{\rm d}y$.

Comment: Sorry, I am still having a hard time understanding how  $\int_{a-1}^a f(x) \ dx =\int_{a-1}^a f(y) \ dy  $. Would you mind elaborating a little more?

Comment: Well, in the expression "$I=\int_a^b f(x) \,{\rm d}x$", the letter $x$ is a mute variable. Then we can exchange it for whatever we want (for example, $I=\int_a^b f(\xi)\,{\rm d}\xi$), in particular $I=\int_a^b f(y)\,{\rm d}y$.

Comment: It is the same as when we write $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.

Comment: Thank you! $\qquad\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, substitution.  Let $u= a - y$. Then $\mathrm{d}u= -\mathrm{d}y$. When $y = 0$, $u = a$ and when $y = 1$, $u = a - 1$. So
$$
    \int_0^1 f(a - y) \,\mathrm{d}y
  = \int_a^{a-1} f(u) \,(-\mathrm{d}u).
$$
But $\int_A^B f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = -\int_B^A f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ so
$$
    \int_a^{a-1} f(u) \, (-\mathrm{d}u)
  = -\int_a^{a-1} f(u) \,\mathrm{d}u
  = \int_{a-1}^a f(u) \,\mathrm{d}u.
$$